# Replace hard coded values with data from table

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently, I have 3 affiliations hard-coded in a query. They serve as a heirarchy: `1 = Faculty, 2 = Staff, 3 = Student`. If a user from the `affiliations_tbl` table has more than one affiliation (example: a Staff member who is also a Student), it will use their Staff affiliation since it is higher on the heirarchy that is defined with the `partition by` and `decode()`.

```
SELECT x2.emplid,
       scc_afl_code
  FROM (SELECT x.emplid,
               scc_afl_code,
               row_number() over(partition BY x.emplid ORDER BY x.affil_order) r
          FROM (SELECT t.emplid,
                       scc_afl_code,
                       DECODE(scc_afl_code,
                              'FACULTY',
                              1,
                              'STAFF',
                              2,
                              'STUDENT',
                              3,
                              999) affil_order
                  FROM affiliations_tbl t
                 WHERE t.scc_afl_code IN
                       (SELECT a.scc_afl_code
                          FROM affiliation_groups_tbl a
                         WHERE a.group = 'COLLEGE')) x) x2
 WHERE x2.r = 1;
```

I have created a table that will store affiliation groups `affiliation_groups_tbl` so I can scale this by adding data to the table, rather than changing the hard-coded values in this query. Example: Instead of adding `'CONSULTANT', 4` to the `decode()` list, I would add it to the table, so I wouldn't have to modify the SQL.

```
scc_afl_code |  group  | group_name | sort_order 
-------------+---------+------------+-----------
FACULTY      | COLLEGE | Faculty    |     1
STAFF        | COLLEGE | Staff      |     2
STUDENT      | COLLEGE | Student    |     3
```

I've already updated the latter half of the query to only select `scc_afl_code` that are in the `COLLEGE_GROUP` group. **How can I properly update the first part of the query to use the table as a hierarchy?**

Comment: I think I may have figured this out... I was over thinking things. I should join my new table to `affiliations_tbl` to get the `sort_order` field, then select the lowest number. Going to try to implement this now, but let me know if you have an idea for another method.

Comment: I think you may have figured this out, too - what you describe sounds like the right way to do it. Please write back if you run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try a piece of code below instead decode in the select clause of your statement:

```
coalesce((
    select g.sort_order 
    from affiliation_groups_tbl g
    where g.scc_afl_code = t.scc_afl_code ), 999)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like that

```
    create table dictionary
    (id number,
    code varchar2(32),
    name varchar2(32),
    sort number);

    insert into dictionary (id, code, name, sort) values (16, 'B', 'B name', 1);
    insert into dictionary (id, code, name, sort) values (23, 'A', 'A name', 2);
    insert into dictionary (id, code, name, sort) values (15, 'C', 'C name', 4);
    insert into dictionary (id, code, name, sort) values (22, 'D', 'D name', 3);

    select partition,
           string,
           decode(string, 'B', 1, 'A', 2, 'D', 3, 'C', 4, 999) decode,
           row_number() over(partition by partition order by decode(string, 'B', 1, 'A', 2, 'D', 3, 'C', 4, 999)) ordering
      from (select mod(level, 3) partition, chr(65 + mod(level, 5)) string
              from dual
            connect by level <= 8)
    minus

    -- Alternate --
    select partition,
           string,
           nvl(t.sort, 999) nvl,
           row_number() over(partition by partition order by nvl(t.sort, 999)) ordering
      from (select mod(level, 3) partition, chr(65 + mod(level, 5)) string
              from dual
            connect by level <= 8) r
      left join dictionary t
        on t.code = r.string;
```